# PHP - force-download dialog box: set specific actions based on user's input?

Tags: php, force-download

I'm setting up a portal where users can listen, upload or download mp3 files but the download option only becomes available (not implemented yet) when a user previously uploads an mp3 file to the server.

I have a field (named 'descargas') in a mysql table that keeps track of the available downloads a user has after uploading (increment field value by 1) or downloading an mp3 file (decrement field value by 1). I also use a session variable ($_SESSION['descargas']) to keep track of the available downloads.

The upload part is fine but I have a small problem with the download part: I need to somehow tell php that if the user chooses not to download the file when the dialog appears, then the decrement by 1 not be applied.

I'm using the force-download method for php (but using a POST method, as opposed to the official GET method for the fix) with a separate download file located in the same directory  as the mp3 files and my current problem is that a user's available downloads will be deducted by one, even if they choose not to go ahead with the download.

Another problem is the fact that even when the available downloads equal 0, the user still gets the save dialog and can download any file after clicking on its link.

Here's the download file:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_POST['file_name']) || empty($_POST['file_name'])) {

    session_destroy();
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['file_name'])) {

    $file = basename($_POST['file_name']);    
    $size = filesize($file);

    $user=$_SESSION['usuario'];           
    $conexion4=mysqli_connect('localhost','usuariomusica2','1MusicUser1','musica2'); 

    $sentencia12=mysqli_query($conexion4, "update musica2.usuarios set descargas=descargas-1 where usuario='$user' and descargas > 0");   
    $sentencia13=mysqli_query($conexion4, "select * from musica2.usuarios where usuario='$user'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia13);
    $_SESSION['descargas']=$row[5];

// Definir headers

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
    header('Expires: 0'); 
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg3');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

// Descargar archivo

    readfile($file);
}

else {

    die('El archivo no existe.');
}

?>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. If I have to take a completely different route and implement the download part with javascript and / or ajax so I can solve my problem, I'll do it.

P:S I have also noticed that, when clicking on the  tags for any given song on the main page, the browser's URL never changes to 'download.php', which is the name of the php page that handles the downloads, even though the page is being visited.

Comment: When you send the content-disposition header like you did, any output from `download.php` will be the mp3 type file. You can assume the mp3 file to be downloaded is `download.php`, so that's why `download.php` won't show on the address bar. Headers should go before any output. You can't mix javascript with PHP like that. It will only output the javascript as a downloadable mp3 given that you place the headers correctly.

Comment: ok, I've removed the jquery but I still can't solve the main issue. If it´s not possible with php but possible with ajax, I'll take that other approach. Anyone?